# Insertar objetos que estan dentro de my array enviarlos a mi php _?

Tags: php, angular

No tengo mucha exp con php pero quisiera una idea o una manera mas conveniente para hacer esta api

que a la hora yo insertar los datos de mi array a mi php
sea de esta manera

```
id   cantidad    producto  fecha
1        23      refresco  12/10/2022
1        24      jugo      12/10/2022
1        35      agua      12/10/2022
2        44      batida    13/10/2022
3        56      cerveza   14/10/2022
4        65      ponche    15/10/2022
```

seria algo así como una orden de compra, para poder identificar cual fue su pedido "articulos" y en que dia

lo que tengo en mi api

```
if (isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata)) {

    $array_conduces  = json_decode($postdata);

    foreach ($array_conduces as &$valor) {
    
         $codigointerno = $valor->codigointerno;
         $descripcion = $valor->descripcion;
         $fecha= $valor->fecha;
         $cantidad = $valor->cantidad;
         $codigobarra = $valor->codigobarra;
      
         $sql = "INSERT INTO `ordendecompra`(`idorden`,`codigointerno`, `descripcion`, `fecha`, `cantidad`) 
                VALUES ('$idorden','$codigointerno','$descripcion', now() ,'$cantidad') ";
     
         $stmt = mysqli_query( $con, $sql); 
                
                
         $sql2= "INSERT INTO `fechadecompra`(`idorden`, `codigobarra`, `fecha`, `cantidad`) 
                 VALUES ('$idorden','$codigobarra',now(),'$cantidad)";
                    
         echo($sql);
         echo($sql2);

         $stmt = mysqli_query( $con, $sql2); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Procura no usar concatenación para crear las consultas, puedes estar expuesto a inyección SQL, preferiblemente usar sentencias preparadas (prepared statements): https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php#:~:text=Una%20sentencia%20preparada%20o%20una,sentencia%20repetidamente%20con%20gran%20eficiencia.&text=La%20ejecuci%C3%B3n%20de%20sentencias%20preparadas,servidor%20de%20bases%20de%20datos.

Comment: mysqli tiene un método que te devuelve cada fila como un objeto, puedes usar dicho método y crear un array de objetos. De todos modos no se entiende mucho qué es lo quieres exactamente, si es insertar o si es mostrar los datos.

Comment: ¿porque has puesto la etiqueta **angular**?  El código de la pregunta es PHP según parece.  Quítala para no confundir a quien pretenda ayudarte, gracias.